# Is it good practice to store objects using utility classes?

Tags: java, class, object, utility

This is mainly a coding style question. I was wondering if it is a good coding principle to store and get objects from utility classes?

For example, let's say I created a list of integers and I want that list to be used by other classes. However, in order to do this, I have to pass the list inside each class every time I want to use/edit the list.
Instead of doing this, is it a good practice to create a utility class that 'gets' this list for me every time I want to use it?

Using a utility class cleans up my code. However, I have heard that it is considered a bad practice to even use a utility class. Thanks!

```
public class ThisExample {

    private static final List<Integer> thisList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static List<Integer> getMoveHistory() {
        return thisList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Globally accessible objects can be difficult to debug and will tightly couple your codebase, but it's not an uncommon pattern. There is a high probability that a better way to solve whatever core problem you're working on exists.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the fast response! Perhaps I am wording this incorrectly - I apologize. I've been looking for ways to make my code easier to read - creating globally accessible objects was one of the solutions to this. If I did do this, would it typically be frowned upon to do so?

Comment: The problem isn't using a utility class, it's having an implicit communication channel where multiple instances of a consumer could step on each other. For example, it's very common to run tests in parallel, and they each need their own copy of the move list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest viewing your question in terms of pros and cons, not best practices since the latter are a matter of opinion.

**Pros of using a global container:**

- Easy accessibility to the global variables - each class which will import the container will be able to access the global data.
- Centralization of shared variables - looking for a specific global variable is easy, assuming all of the variables are stored in the same container class.
- Documentation - storing all the globals in one class helps document the context and purpose of the globals - simply group them by context and add a comment explaining their role in the application.
- Simplicity - for smaller code bases/applications, with a single threaded approach and a small number of classes and code flows, using a container of global variables can be a simple and straight forward solution for passing information between entities.

**Cons of using a global container:**

- Class coupling - all of the classes which will use global variables will have to import the same Container class, which will cause a dependency on the container class by many other classes. Changes to the container class will now affect many other classes at the same time.
- Single point of failure - a lot of the application code flows will pass throw the container class. This makes certain approaches (such as using a synchronization lock) impractical to use on the container class, due to performance considerations for example.
- Difficulty in debugging - since many elements of the application will inevitably access the global variables, it can be more difficult to debug their contents, especially in multi-threaded solutions.
- Object-Oriented anti-pattern - if the OO approach is focused on encapsulation of code and abstraction of solutions, then the global container is the exact opposite -  shared code which is purely focused on implementations (when using DS global variables, for example).
- Always in memory - A Global container's variables will be in-scope as long as the application runs. Many memory leaks are the result of forgotten, in-scope variables.

References:

- [Pros and Cons of using global variables](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53ae563a-bb7d-4526-b7c6-8e58c7bb62e6/pros-and-cons-of-using-global-variables?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [Global vs Local variables](https://www.cypress.com/file/53276/download)
- [How dangerous are the Global Variables](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?474662-How-dangerous-are-the-Global-Variables)